# Terminator : Window flickers when hit <tab> in screen

Tags: gnome, terminator

I have been using terminator since few days and I m facing an annoying issue. Whenever I hit tab (in screen) , window flickers (becomes black for a micro second and turns normal again). I googled it and found few solutions. One of them being adding

force_no_bell = True

to its config file. Added it but still of no use. When I am not in screen, it doesn't flick though. It happens only in screen. Other than that, its awesome :)

I am using Terminator 0.97 on gnome-shell 3.8 on Ubuntu 13.04

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
vbell off
```

to `.screenrc` file fixed it.

Thanks!